# Integrate VLC player in C# (WPF) project using Vlc.DotNet

Tags: wpf, xaml, vlc

I want to integrate to my project a VLC player to display video cameras streams. For that, I try to use Vlc.DotNet (2.1.126 version) in my WPF project.

My tests are done in the following XAML file (I'm a bit a beginner at XAML/WPF):

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TVSCS_View.VideoDisplay.VideoPlayerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:TVSCS_View.VideoDisplay"
             xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" 
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="controlVideoDisplay"
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=controlVideoDisplay}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid x:Name="videoDisplayLayoutRoot"
              Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=myVlcControl}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <ctrl:VideoCommandsControl x:Name="videoPlayerControl"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       Height="25"
                                       Width="175"
                                       Visibility="Visible"
                                       Margin="10,0,10,20" />
            <ctrl:VideoTimeLineControl x:Name="timeLineControl"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And the associated .cs file is:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;

namespace TVSCS_View.VideoDisplay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logique d'interaction pour VideoPlayerControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class VideoPlayerControl : UserControl
    {
        public VlcControl myVlcControl;

        public VideoPlayerControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MediaPlayer media = new MediaPlayer();

            myVlcControl = new VlcControl();
            var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var currentDirectory = new FileInfo(currentAssembly.Location).DirectoryName;

            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {
                myVlcControl.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(currentDirectory, @"C:\Users\t0115019\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\tvscs_display\packages\VLC\"));
            }

            myVlcControl.MediaPlayer.EndInit();
            myVlcControl.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("C:/Users/Documents/WP_20160908_11_16_53_Pro.mp4"));
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, I have an exception "FillNotFOundException" linked to "myVlcControl.MediaPlayer.EndInit()" line when I execute the application.
If I delete this line, nothing is displayed in the UserControl.

Nota:
I try to integrate the VlcControl using the following method:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TVSCS_View.VideoDisplay.VideoPlayerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:TVSCS_View.VideoDisplay"
             xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" 
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="controlVideoDisplay"
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=controlVideoDisplay}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid x:Name="videoDisplayLayoutRoot"
              Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <wpf:VlcControl x:Name="myVlcControl" />
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

But in this case, i have the following messsage:
*the value of type "VlcControl" cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'*.

Do you have any solution for my little problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *WPF* version of the `VlcControl` is just a [`WindowsFormsHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx) control hosting the *Windows Forms* version of the `VlcControl`. Judging by the error message (*The value of type "VlcControl" cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'*) you're simply missing a reference to the `WindowsFormsIntegration` assembly, in which the `WindowsFormsHost` is defined (it can be found under *Assemblies → Framework* in the reference manager).

---

Here's a fully working example of a *WPF* window hosting the *VLC* player. You need to install the [Vlc.DotNet.Wpf NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vlc.DotNet.Wpf/) (and its dependencies) and reference the `WindowsFormsIntegration` assembly.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="HelloVlc.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf">
    <vlc:VlcControl x:Name="vlcPlayer" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectory =
            //replace this path with an appropriate one
            new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\");
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.EndInit();
        vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("http://download.blender.org/peach/" +
            "bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Its work!
Sadly, it seems that WPF video is always on top with Vlc.DotNet.

Comment: @Tchebourachka Unfortunately, that is just how the windows forms host works.

Comment: There are other alternatives. It seems that meta.vlc (https://github.com/higankanshi/Meta.Vlc) has not the airspace issue. The same happens with the old version of vlcdotnet

Comment: Thanks, I try to use Meta.Vlc. 

I add Meta.Vlc and Metal.Vlc.Wpf in my project references and I modify the AssemblyInfo.cs to add a "VlcSettings" line. 

But If I add <wpf:VlcPlayer x:Name="myPlayer" /> (with xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:Meta.Vlc.Wpf;assembly=Meta.Vlc.Wpf") in my XAML file, it doesn't work: I have "The name VlcPlayer does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Meta.Vlc.Wpf;assembly=Meta.Vlc.Wpf". Any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: late commend but still valid. you need that on your xml `        xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf">`