# VLC Media player in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, video-streaming, vlc

When I'm trying to integrate Meta.Vlc.Wpf media player from Nuget Package, I'm getting the following error

[image]

How to solve this.

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723674/integrate-vlc-player-in-c-sharp-wpf-project-using-vlc-dotnet?rq=1) using [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vlc.DotNet.Wpf)

while using that

I'm facing issue as

> VlcControl does not contain a definition for 'MediaPlayer and no
>   accessible extension method 'MediaPlayer' accepting a first argument
>   of type -VIcContror could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code and/or error messages (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245), [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and [Pictures of exceptions are not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)).

Comment: @elgonzo okay , i will change.

Comment: Look at the error message you got: "_VlcControl does not contain a definition for 'MediaPlayer and no accessible extension method 'MediaPlayer' accepting a first argument of type VIcContror could be found_" is rather self-explanatory. You are trying to access a `VlcControl` member (or extension method) called _MediaPlayer_, but the `VlcControl` type does not have such a public member/extension method (as the compiler/error message tells you). I guess you need to revisit and double-check on the documentation and/or guides that made you think that _VlcControl_ would have a _MediaPlayer_ member.

Comment: Share full code