# Problem adding vlc to my WPF project using Vlc.DotNet

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc, vlc.dotnet

I want to integrate the vlc player to my project in order to display the stream of an IP camera. I was following this [Integrate VLC player in C# (WPF) project using Vlc.DotNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723674/integrate-vlc-player-in-c-sharp-wpf-project-using-vlc-dotnet) to make a demo. Here is my c# code:

```
    using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;

namespace RTSPyVLC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Lógica de interacción para MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.VlcLibDirectory =
                //replace this path with an appropriate one
                new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\");
            vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.EndInit();
            vlcPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play(new Uri("http://download.blender.org/peach/" +
                "bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi"));
        }
    }
}
```

I do the same, but an error appears: VlcControl does not contain a definition for "MediaPlayer"...
And its true, the class VlcControl doesn contain it. The question is if I adding the wrong package (Vlc.DotNet.wpf by ZeBobo5 added with NuGet) or there is another way to integrate the vlc player with this library. If you know about an example or a guide it would be magnificient.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: could you show your wpf code?

Comment: I have solve the problem, thanks anyway. What I would want to know is how to reduce the buffer in order to reduce the delay.

Answer (score 1):

you have an help [WIKI for VLC](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Getting-started), at the bottom of the web page you have all information about wpf with a sample.

in wpf:

```
<Vlc:VlcControl xmlns:Vlc="clr-namespace:Vlc.DotNet.Wpf;assembly=Vlc.DotNet.Wpf" x:Name="MyControl" />
```

In your view constructor, after the call to InitializeComponent()

```
  var vlcLibDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

        var options = new string[]
        {
            // VLC options can be given here. Please refer to the VLC command line documentation.
        };

        this.MyControl.SourceProvider.CreatePlayer(vlcLibDirectory, options);

        // Load libvlc libraries and initializes stuff. It is important that the options (if you want to pass any) and lib directory are given before calling this method.
        this.MyControl.SourceProvider.MediaPlayer.Play("http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_h264.mov");
```

Comment: The wiki link you mentionned is a good place to start. However, for perf reasons, I usually recommend not to use the Wpf control and just wrap the WinForms control instead (see the readme). One more tip : There is now a NuGet package to install and redistribute libvlc for windows (see the wiki)

Comment: Thanks, that's worked! I had to add the vlc plugins to the repository, which I completly forget.